# Is it possible to convert mp4 video data into webm?

Tags: python, flask, video-streaming, html5-video

I am streaming a video from a URL, is it possible to convert that binary data into webm, and ogg for HTML5 video support?

[image]

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible? Sure.

MP4 is a container for h264, h265, or other similar video encodings. WebM is a container for VP8, VP9, and other similar royalty-free encodings.

Since nothing contained in an MP4 can be just moved into a WebM, you'll have to re-encode the video data into VP8, VP9, or some other encoding that is supported by WebM. This is a very CPU intensive process, which is going to matter if you're doing this at pretty much any scale, especially if you're trying to do it in real-time.